# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = p$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Given a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ of real numbers such that
> $$\begin{align}
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_na_{n+1} - a_{n-1}a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}^2 - a_na_{n+2}} &= p + q && (1)\\[1mm]
> \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n^2 - a_{n-1}a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}^2 - a_na_{n+2}} &= pq && (2)\end{align}$$
> where $|p| < |q|$, prove that
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = p$$

---

### **Attempts:**

**Idea #1:** Let us denote $b_n = \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$. If we divide both numerators and denominators of $(1)$ and $(2)$ by $a_na_{n+2}$ and $a_{n+1}a_n$, respectively, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+2}} - \dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}}{\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+2}} - 1} &= p+q && (1') \\[1mm]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\dfrac{a_n}{a_{a+1}} - \dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}}{\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - \dfrac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}} &= pq && (2')
\end{align}$$
which now can be written as
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_{n+1}b_n - b_nb_{n-1}}{b_{n+1} - b_n} &= p+q  && (1'') \\[1mm]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n - b_{n-1}}{\dfrac{1}{b_{n+1}} - \dfrac{1}{b_{n}}} &= -pq && (2'')
\end{align}$$

Now, every numerator and denominator contains the difference of consecutive terms of some sequence (reminds me of Cesaro-Stolz, but that cannot be applied here).

---

**Idea #2:** The given conditions can be written as
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\begin{vmatrix}a_n & a_{n-1} \\ a_{n+2} & a_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a_{n+1} & a_{n} \\ a_{n+2} & a_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}} &= p + q && (1')\\[2mm]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\begin{vmatrix}a_n & a_{n-1} \\ a_{n+1} & a_{n}\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a_{n+1} & a_{n} \\ a_{n+2} & a_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}} &= pq && (2')\end{align}$$
Now, maybe a bit of Linear Algebra could be incorporated somehow.

If we set <sup>[(B. Grossman)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134053/prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-fraca-na-n1-p#comment8552357_4134053)</sup>
$$\begin{align} x_n = \frac{\begin{vmatrix}a_n & a_{n-1} \\ a_{n+2} & a_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a_{n+1} & a_{n} \\ a_{n+2} & a_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}}, \quad  y_n =  \frac{\begin{vmatrix}a_n & a_{n-1} \\ a_{n+1} & a_{n}\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a_{n+1} & a_{n} \\ a_{n+2} & a_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}} \end{align}$$
Then, we have
$$\pmatrix{a_{n+1} & a_{n+2}\\a_n & a_{n+1}} \pmatrix{x_n\\y_n} = \pmatrix{a_n\\a_{n-1}}$$
This gives
$$\frac{a_{n+1}x_n + a_{n+2}y_n}{a_nx_n + a_{n+1}y_n} = \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$$
Dividing the numerator and the denominator by $a_{n+1}$, we get
$$\frac{x_n + \dfrac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}y_n}{\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}x_n + y_n} = \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$$
Noting that $x_n \to p+q$, $y_n \to pq$ and assuming that $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} \to A$, and sending $n$ to infinity, we get
$$\frac{p+q + Apq}{\dfrac{1}{A}(p+q) + pq} = A$$
which simplifies to
$$0=0$$

I think I did something wrong somewhere.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $B$ is the expression in the first limit and $C$ is the expression in the second limit, I would compute $-B+\sqrt{B^2-4C}$.

Comment: With [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), we can identify the quotients as the entries of the solution to a system of equations: if we define
\begin{align}
x_n = \frac{\begin{vmatrix}a_n & a_{n-1} \\ a_{n+2} & a_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a_{n+1} & a_{n} \\ a_{n+2} & a_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}}, \quad 
y_n =  \frac{\begin{vmatrix}a_n & a_{n-1} \\ a_{n+1} & a_{n}\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a_{n+1} & a_{n} \\ a_{n+2} & a_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}}, \end{align}
Then we have
$$
\pmatrix{a_{n+1} & a_{n+2}\\a_n & a_{n+1}} \pmatrix{x_n\\y_n} = \pmatrix{a_n\\a_{n-1}}
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, I also had something roughly similar in mind. Could this help?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Added more thoughts with your hint. I think I made a mistake though since the answer has been different than the desired one.

Comment: @VIVID I think that I have a sign error for $y_n$, that might explain your incorrect result

Comment: @VIVID Actually, even with the correct substitution you end up getting $0=0$. One way to proceed is as follows. suppose that $a_n/a_{n-1} \to A$ and that $A \neq 0$. Divide by $a_{n-1}$ to get the equation $$\pmatrix{a_{n+1}/a_{n-1} & a_{n+2}/a_{n-1}\\a_n/a_{n-1} & a_{n+1}/a_{n-1}}\pmatrix{x_n\\-y_n} = \pmatrix{a_n/a_{n-1}\\1}.$$ Letting $n \to \infty$ in the above equation yields
$$ \pmatrix{A^2 & A^3\\ A & A^2} \pmatrix{p+q\\-pq} = \pmatrix{A\\1} \implies\\
A(p+q) - A^2 pq = 1 \implies\\
(pq)A^2 - (p+q)A + 1 = 0 \implies\\
(pA - 1)(qA - 1) = 0 \implies\\
A = 1/p \text{ or } A = 1/q.
$$

Comment: That said, I see no way to differentiate between $1/p$ and $1/q$ with this method, and I don't know how to justify the assumption that $a_n/a_{n-1}$ converges.

Comment: Another idea is to use the substitution $b_n = p^n a_n$. This leads to the equations
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(b_nb_{n+1} - b_{n-1}b_{n+2})}{(b_{n+1}^2 - b_nb_{n+2})} &= 1 + q/p\\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{b_n^2 - b_{n-1}b_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}^2 - b_nb_{n+2}} &= q/p,
\end{align}
and we've reduced the problem to showing that $b_n/b_{n+1} \to 1$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you. I will try to use your hints.

Comment: Can you tell us where the problems comes from?

Comment: Previous identical question found [with SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B+%5Cfrac%7Ba_n%5E2+-+a_%7Bn-1%7Da_%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7Ba_%7Bn%2B1%7D%5E2+-+a_na_%7Bn%2B2%7D%7D+%7D%24)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. I was wondering why Approach0 was not working for some time now...

Comment: @VIVID: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57889293#57889293

Comment: @MartinR I didn't understand why you used *problems* (in plural). This problem comes from an old book written by Sadovnichiy and Podkoldzin.

Comment: That was a typo. – It is always a good idea to add the source of a problem to the question.

Comment: @MartinR Ok. Got you, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following proof is not complete, hoped this is helpful to you.

Denote $b_n=\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ , then
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n(b_{n+1}-b_{n-1})}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=p+q,\quad \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n b_{n+1}(b_{n}-b_{n-1})}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=pq.$$

If you **assume that** $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n=x$ exists, since
$$p+q=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n(b_{n+1}-b_{n-1})}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}[\frac{b_n(b_{n}-b_{n-1})}{b_{n+1}-b_n}+b_n],$$
hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n(b_{n}-b_{n-1}\ )}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=y$ also exists. Moreover,
$$x+y=p+q,\quad xy=pq\implies
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x=p \\ y=q 
\end{array}\right.,\ or
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x=q \\ y=p
\end{array}\right..$$

If you can **check that** $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |b_n|\le \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\frac{b_n(b_{n}-b_{n-1}\ )}{b_{n+1}-b_n}|$, then
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n=x=p.$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**
Call
$$
X_n=\frac{a_na_{n+1}-a_{n-1}a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}^2-a_na_{n+2}}\\
Y_n=\frac{a_{n}^2-a_{n-1}a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}^2-a_na_{n+2}}
$$
then
$$
\lim_nX_n=p+q\\
\lim_nY_n=pq
$$
thus
$$
\lim_n\frac{X_n}{Y_n}=\frac{p+q}{pq}
$$
but
$$
\frac{X_n}{Y_n}
=\frac{a_na_{n+1}-a_{n-1}a_{n+2}}{a_{n}^2-a_{n-1}a_{n+1}}\;.
$$
Then you get
$$
\frac{X_n}{Y_nY_{n-1}}=
\frac{a_na_{n+1}-a_{n-1}a_{n+2}}{a_{n-1}^2-a_{n-2}a_{n}}
$$
and inductively
$$
\frac{X_n}{Y_nY_{n-1}\cdots Y_2}=
\frac{a_na_{n+1}-a_{n-1}a_{n+2}}{a_{1}^2-a_{0}a_{2}}
$$
from which
$$
\frac{X_n}{Y_nY_{n-1}\cdots Y_2}(a_{1}^2-a_{0}a_{2})+a_{n-1}a_{n+2}=a_na_{n+1}
$$
divide by $a_{n+1}^2$ and work on LHS.